# z.lib problems while porting qt creator projet to windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, zlib

I am trying to port a Qt5.9 project from Mac to Windows 10.
I was able to compile the project easily in a ubuntu installation.
While trying to build it for windows, i had problems with finding zlib include headers with

```
#include<zlib.h>
```

That i corrected after following answers here on Stack to

```
#include<QtZlib/zlib.h>
```

Now i have problems in LINK phase, it can not open the file z.lib

Problem is i downloaded zlib packages, builds, source code and could not find a z.lib. Only different named libs. Searching in google i could only find people with the same problem, z.lib is not one of the libs included in zlib installation.

This is my project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets websockets

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    api.cpp \
    app.cpp

HEADERS += \
    api.hpp \
    app.hpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc


LIBS += -lz
```

I tried putting all possible dll and lib files in the project folder. None of them is named z.lib though.

Comment: Possibly try adding something like: QMAKE_LFLAGS+=-L/path/to/zlib/dll could help ? No idea if it does, but it might.

Comment: tried that in many ways (with "" in path, with dll name in path, with foward and backward slashes) to no avail, thanks though

Comment: Alternatively, when you run qmake it should generate another build file (tbh I'm not sure what the standard build file for windows is, for linux it would be a makefile)... you could try seeing if editing that directly could help (though it would be a last-ditch solution

Comment: You stated that you couldn't find "z.lib". This might be a typo but may be not. The lib file to link is probably called **zlib1.lib**, the DLL resp. **zlib1.dll**.

Comment: thats the whole problem, i can only find answers on the internet regardin zlib1.dll/lib, but the error says z.lib.

Comment: @Diedre, you have put in your project file: `LIBS += -lz`, hence a **z.lib** will be required. If you don't have such file put the name of the file you have, e.g. **zlib1.lib**, or in other words type the following: `LIBS += -lzlib1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem updating my Qt installation to use MinGw 5.3 32bit. I was using VisualStudio 2015 as the compiler before.

Only changing the compiler to MinGw (g++) 5.3 made everything work with the same pro file i posted in the original question. Thanks everybody who tried to help!

Answer (score 2):

The symbols for zlib are already part of the qt libraries. As long as you do not try to link the zlib explicitly it should work. At least it does work for me.

add to your project file:

```
!win32 {
    LIBS += -lz
}
```

Comment: i tried that and i didn't work, but i managed to solve changing the compiler. Thanks!